# AngularJs ui bootstrap using ng-repeat and id's to open calendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently having an issue with angular. First of all note that am not very familiar with angular and I searched around and tried many different solutions but couldn't really find out how to fix my issue.

Here is my html (every item.Id is unique):

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in employment.Items">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFromEmp" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="date-picker input-group dp-blue" ng-class="{ 'is-opened': '{{item.Id}}' == true}">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar ma-icon"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line" ng-class="{ 'fg-toggled': '{{item.Id}}' == true }">
                                <input ng-click="open($event, '{{item.Id}}')" id="inputFromEmp" type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
                                       show-weeks="false" ng-model="item.From" is-open="item.Id" min-date="null" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                        close-text="Close" date-disabled placeholder="Select Date" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is the html output we care about:

```
<div class="date-picker input-group dp-blue" ng-class="{ 'is-opened': '3017' == true}">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar ma-icon"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line" ng-class="{ 'fg-toggled': '3017' == true }">
                                <input ng-click="open($event, '3017')" id="inputFromEmp" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-date" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" show-weeks="false" ng-model="item.From" is-open="item.Id"
```

Above you can see is-open"item.Id" doesn't feed from the model. I also tried is-open="{{item.Id}}" and it breaks out. I also did is-open="'{{item.Id}}'" which works and it prints out is-open="'3017'", the problem with that though is that is-open doesn't accept that format so it still breaks.
The only way to get it working this way is to print is-open="3017" which so far I haven't been able to do.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix it by using a dirty hack really... I am doing a setAttribute('is-open', value) via javascript.

I'll leave this here in case anyone else uses it.